# Social buttons using Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I'm trying to add some social buttons to my website, the styling is correct but the icons aren't appearing. I assume this must be an issue with Font Awesome as that's where the icons come from but I can't see where I've gone wrong.

I linked it in the head like so:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and the buttons in the body like so:

```
<div id="contact_page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4 pull-center">
        <button class="btn btn-twitter"><i class="icon-twitter"></i> | Connect with Twitter</button><br>
        <button class="btn btn-linkedin"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i> | Connect with LinkedIn</button><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: is Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons loaded?

Comment: i believe so, aren't the icons from awesome font though?

Answer (score 38):

Since you're trying to use the Font Awesome 4.0.3 then you'll have to use the latest class names to have it right. Instead of `icon-*` you'll have to use the `fa fa-*` (more changes in the [official examples](http://fontawesome.io/examples/))

In your case change the `<i>` to:

```
<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
<i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
```

If you want to have something more advanced than just an icon and a simple separator you could check the [Social Buttons for Bootstrap](http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/) (Disclaimer: I'm the creator) which works nicely with the latest versions and it's very flexible if you want to add more.

[image: Social Buttons for Bootstrap Preview]

Comment: Add the class fw for fixed width as you suggested some time ago ;)

Comment: I just get empty boxes with that css plugin

Answer (score 4):

Probably you don't have these classes.

Check this: 
[Social buttons for Bootstrap](http://noizwaves.github.io/bootstrap-social-buttons/)

or this example:
[Social media icons with font awesome](http://opensourcehacker.com/2013/04/22/charming-social-media-icons-with-font-awesome-and-css3/)

Comment: I used the first example for this, I still can't see where I went wrong!

Comment: One more ready to use buttons: http://ostr.io/code/html-social-like-share-buttons-no-javascript.html